# Using HSQL MEMORY TABLE with grails

Tags: grails, hsqldb

Is that possible to define some kind of mapping in grails so `CREATE TABLE` is replaced with `CREATE MEMORY TABLE` for particular grails domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do this for all tables, you could create a custom Dialect and override `getCreateTableString()` but there's no way to know the current table name, so it can be selectively applied.

But you can take the approach I suggested here: [grails limited table creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935088/grails-limited-table-creation/3935738#3935738). You would just override `generateSchemaCreationScript()` and if you find the table(s) you're looking for, you can replace the 'create table' string with 'create memory table'.

Comment: Nice work Burt, that custom configuration class is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

The create table statements are generated by Hibernate's hbm2ddl feature. I don't think there is a way to configure the syntax of the create statement other than the table name itself and the columns.

You would have to manually manage the schema creation using a plugin like Autobase or Liquibase (or whatever they have coming in Grails 1.4 to handle DB migrations).