# Grails - Can you avoid having Gorm/Hibernate establish Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, foreign-keys, grails-orm

Is there an option you can set somewhere in the configuration of Grails to avoid having it setup Foreign Keys? I'm using MySQL if that matters.

Comment: You need to clarify - an example of what you're doing and what you want would help a lot.

Comment: I like not to have any Foreign Keys when I first start off a project. I'd like to be able to drop a table, and have it recreated by 'update' mode without stopping me based off foreign key restrictions. I want to be able to dump some of my data that has organically grown through use during development without dumping all of it.

Comment: @Burt, I'm looking for a simple way to do this. see above for reasoning. I would like to handle this in the hbm2dll, and not come up with some hackish way of looping through all the foreign keys in MySQL and dropping them via MySQL DDL statements from the BootStrap

Comment: I need to do this same thing also and would not like to go "the Bootstrap way" with it. Any updates on the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Hibernate, this may help: http://blog.cherouvim.com/disabling-foreign-key-generation-in-hbm2ddl/

Looks like you can also override the DDL generation as described here: [grails limited table creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935088/grails-limited-table-creation)

However, I'd try to go with the first approach if possible.